# Embed Spring Security login form to an existing page

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

How do I add the spring security login form to an existing page?

For example, let's say I have the following test.jsp page (which is not a spring login form page):

```
<html>
    <head>Existing Page</head>

    <body>
         <div id="login-form"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like to add the login form configured in my spring-security.xml inside the login-form div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically I believe people just put the form right in the page (i.e. within the div you have there.) Something like:

```
<form id="blah" action="/j_spring_security_check">
  <input type="text" name="j_username" />
  <input type="text" name="j_password" />
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="login" />
  <input type="reset" name="reset" />
</form>
```

Then use your css to make it fit the look and feel of the rest of your application.